# if condition not working comparing item to __ in bash

Tags: bash, shell

When I do an echo $item, it gives me the result as:
__

after which I do

```
if [ "${item}" = "__" ]; then
    $item = ""
    fi
```

and again echo $item it still gives me __
and an error :   __: command not found
and its not getting changed to empty string, can someone plz help

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Hummm... why it should be changed? `$item` contains `__`. You compare `x$item`, which is `x__` against `__`. The strings are different, so you don't enter the `if` body and the `$item` variable is not changed.

Code behaves correctly, why do you think it should be different?

UPDATE (after your question rewriting):

There are several errors in the code:

- In the condition, you are not using the comparison operator. You are using the assignment operator. Change `=` for `==`.
- You are trying to assign a variable usng a dollar sign in the left hand side of the operation. Don't use `$` for the LHS.
- You are adding spaces to the sides of the assigment operator. Wrong again.

Proper code should be:

```
if [ "${item}" == "__" ]; then
    item=""
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, even without x it gives an error and value is unchanged